# How to increase timeout limit of a specific job in kubernetes

Tags: java, linux, shell, kubernetes

I need to call an API via curl command inside a shell file which is taking more than 2min. to complete the entire process and bring back the status response.
As a result, the pod gets into error state and again starts retrying which results into multiple calls to that API.

I don't want the pod to get into Error state as it gets back the response as 504 Gateway Timeout.
Is there any provision to increase the time-out limit of the pod or I need to increase java API response time limit so that it does not responds with 504.
I tried at job level by using -m or --max-time-out in curl command and request-time-out parameter under containers section of deployment yaml but nothing worked.

Comment: It seems like your problem is the API that returns 504. Either increase the timeout for that (perhaps some proxy in the middle?) or make the API operation asynchronous.

Comment: @JurajMartinka:Could you please guide me how to make the API operation asynchronous. Also I tried giving setConnectTimeout(150000); but it didnot help.

Comment: Building asynchronous API depends on the specifics of the project. About the timeout: can you observe the request at the backend (perhaps with logs) and see how long it takes to process? On the client side, does the error happen after the 150 seconds (the timeout) or sooner?

Comment: it takes around 2mins. or slight more than that. I guess in client-side pod is running timed-out after 2min. Not sure how then in retry of pod , its able to complete the process then